# Kth minimum element using quickselect with random pivot

Tags: java, algorithm, quicksort

I am trying to find the kth smallest in an array using quickselect algorithm. But, when I try to select the pivot randomly, the output coming is also random.

Following is my method implementation,

```
    static int findKthMin(int[]arr, int n, int k) {
        int l=0 , r=n-1;
        Random random = new Random();
        while(true) {
            int x = random.nextInt(r+1-l) + l; // When using x = r (works correctly)
            int pivot = arr[x];
            int idx = l;
            for(int i=l;i<=r;i++) {
                if(arr[i] < pivot) {
                    int temp = arr[idx];
                    arr[idx] = arr[i];
                    arr[i] = temp;
                    
                    idx++;
                }
            }
            arr[x] = arr[idx];
            arr[idx] = pivot;
            
            if(idx == k-1) return pivot;
            
            if(idx > k-1) {
                r = idx-1;
            } else {
                l = idx;
            }
        }
    }
```

Here, `n` is size of array and `k` is the kth minimum element to be found.
The code works fine when I use `x=r`.

My guess is that something is wrong in the condition

```
   for(int i=l;i<=r;i++) {
       if(arr[i] < pivot) {
            int temp = arr[idx];
            arr[idx] = arr[i];
            arr[i] = temp;

            idx++;
       }
   }
```

But I can't figure out what is wrong and how to fix it. I have spent hours debugging it and changing the code but can figure out the problem.

Here are the test cases I'm trying,

```
6               // n
7 10 4 3 20 15  //arr
3               // k
```

and,

```
5             // n
7 10 4 20 15  // arr
4             // k
```

With these test cases, random pivot is giving any of the array element as the output. 
Any hint of what might be the bug will be very helpful.

Comment: I'm assuming you adapted this from the Wikipedia page? You forgot the step where you move the pivot element to the back before doing any swapping. Also, this loop should run until `i < r`.

Comment: @NicoSchertler Thank you for the suggestion. Even though I didn't refer any of Wiki implementation, it was pretty stupid of me for not thinking of just swapping the random pivot element to the last element. It works fine after that.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

After the suggestion from @Nico, I just needed to swap the pivot element with the last one.
Following is the complete working snippet,

```
    static int findKthMin(int[]arr, int n, int k) {
        int l=0 , r=n-1;
        Random random = new Random();
        while(true) {
            int x = random.nextInt(r+1-l) + l; // When using x = r (works correctly)

            //Swap random pivot with the last index element
            int temp = arr[x];
            arr[x] = arr[r];
            arr[r] = temp;

            int pivot = arr[r];

            int idx = l;
            for(int i=l;i<=r;i++) {
                if(arr[i] < pivot) {
                    temp = arr[idx];
                    arr[idx] = arr[i];
                    arr[i] = temp;

                    idx++;
                }
            }
            arr[r] = arr[idx];
            arr[idx] = pivot;

            if(idx == k-1) return pivot;

            if(idx > k-1) {
                r = idx-1;
            } else {
                l = idx;
            }
        }
    }
```